# Submit string selection form field to server as integer

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.1.0. I have a form_for block in one of my views for a new action. Most of the fields that are being filled out in the form are being stored in the database as integers, but I would like to present them to the user as strings in a select input. For example, the user might have to choose from Bad, OK, Good in a select input, but I would want to store Bad as 1, OK as 2, and Good as 3. I would like to convert the strings to integers in the browser.

What is the recommended way to accomplish this?

I thought about making the integer fields hidden, and then using javascript to convert the selected strings to integers and fill in the hidden integer fields. Does that make any sense or is there a simpler way?

This is not a Rails specific question, but I am using Rails and thought that Rails might have a nice way of doing what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send an array of options to the select helper inside your form_for in your view:

```
<%= f.select :quality, [['Bad', 1], ['OK', 2], ['Good', 3] %>
```

Note, you might need to do some work in your controller to convert these values from strings to integers before saving your model - just check that.

Comment: You actually don't need to do any conversion in the controller. I looked at the html that was generated from this, and the second value in each pair is stored in the value attribute of the option tag. So apparently the functionality I wanted is built right into the select tag. Thanks. I will be using your suggestion.